# Adding raster image to ArcGis Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, layouts

It is [said in manual](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/layouts/add-and-modify-graphics-and-text.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_88C5A01A569D490B850BB349FDF38F74), that

> You can add pictures to your layout. The insert picture command can be
>   found on the Insert tab in the Graphics group.

Unfortunately, I don't have any `Graphics` group in insert tab:

[image]

How to accomplish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't opened a layout, only a scene. Click on `New Layout`, then under the graphics tab you'll have an option to add a picture.

[image]

After you click Picture, you will need to drag out a rectangle that indicates where on the page you want to place it, and then a file browser opens to let you choose your image.

Answer (score 3):

The menus in Pro are context driven, meaning depending what you have active or clicked on will you will see appropriate menus. As stated in the help topic you referenced, you need to have an active layout: `You can add pictures to your **layout**.` Your screen shot shows you're looking at a `Scene`.

Insert a new layout from the **Insert** menu. You'll then have the picture option.